# Magento2: How to disable password autofill on store-configuration?

Tags: magento2, configuration, system.xml

I have 2 fields on my `system.xml`.
The first one is an authentication key (obscured).
The second one is an email.
The thing is, because I use my email & it's also saved in my browser with a password, Chrome autofills my password into the first field, even after I save the right key it loads the form with the saved password from the browser.
Here is an example screenshot of what I mean:
[image: Example Screenshot]

-- Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding the 'autocomplete=off' attribute to your input. You're going to need to create a frontend model and add it to your fields in the system.xml

> NoAutoComplete.php (frontend model)

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\CustomModule\Model\Frontend;

class NoAutoComplete extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field
{
    /**
    @param  \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element
    Output : return string
     */
    protected function _getElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
    {
        $html = '<input id="' . $element->getHtmlId() .
                '" name="' . $element->getName() .
                '" autocomplete="off" />';

        return $html;
    }
}
```

> system.xml

```
   <field id="credentials" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" >
       <label>Credentials</label>
       <frontend_model>Vendor\CustomModule\Model\Frontend\NoAutoComplete</frontend_model>
   </field>
```

Comment: Already tried that, it doesn't work, the browser ignores the autocomplete attribute & fills out the field anyway. I actually suspect that this issue is related to Chrome more than to Magento.

Comment: It seems that certain browsers ignore the autocomplete attribute for password fields. More info here: https://caniuse.com/#search=autocomplete

Comment: Yes, leaving this question opened in case someone have a good idea for a workaround (I thought of adding 2 fake hidden fields at the beginning of the form so Chrome will have something else to autofill...)